# EntityFramework / WCF RIA Services / Oracle / Custom number mapping

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, mapping, numbers, wcf-ria-services

this post is intended as (not optimal) solution for everyone that has to struggle with the same problem and there is only few to no answer in the net atm...
(of cousrse this post will contain information from other sources)

we had problems with custom data type mapping (number) in our project (VS2010/EntityFramework/WCF RIA Services/Oracle ODP.NET) which we were able to solve the following way:

we had to use the following custom oracle number mapping information (because of legacy DB)

```
</connectionStrings>
  <oracle.dataaccess.client>
    <settings>
      <add name="int16" value="edmmapping number(4,0)" />
      <add name="int32" value="edmmapping number(9,0)" />
      <add name="int64" value="edmmapping number(17,0)" />
    </settings>
  </oracle.dataaccess.client>
```

we put this information in App.Config within the project with the EDMX file(s)
now we were able to create our EDMX files with the custom mapping

1) there was a problem that when you restart VS2010 it can happen that upon proeject compilation it wont compile because of an Error 2019, this error is of course related to our custom mapping and its a "VS2010 bug???" maybe but one solution is to open he VS2010 about window then close it then compile... but the better solution might or might not be to add the same information we added to the App.Config file to the devenv.exe.config file...

now we can compile the EDMX project and 
the My.Service.Web (.NET) project that uses the our EDM

2) there is still another problem ... the WCF RIA Service My.Service (SL5) project
has no idea of the App.Config settings so when we try to compile it we will also get the
Error 2019...
adding the mapping information to the Web.Config file did not help
but when we add it to the machine.config file we can finally compile...

SUMMARY: add the mapping information to
App.Config (where your edmx file is)
Machine.Config (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config)
Web.Config (in your web project, not sure if required since we added it to Machine.config)

QUESTION: isn't there a better solution than to add it to Machine.Config?
          I really hope someone has a better one because it will probably restict
          development of other projects...

hope this helps and hope for a better (re)solution

thx and cheers

versions:
VS2010 SP1
EntityFramework 4.1
WCF RIA Services 1 SP2
Oracle 11g (ODAC/ODP.NET 11.2.0.3.0)